# HTML5 read file from IPad document Directory

Tags: javascript, ios, html, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have created html5 based app in Titanium for ipad. Using Titanium I have stored a file named `demo.txt` in

> /Users/anonymous/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FE1CFXXX0AC-D5BD-9615-C58D80B5A9C6/data/Containers/Data/Application/2D25XXXX-4687-B28A-1EA7B7EA3013/Documents/

in same application itself. Now I need to want to access content of `demo.txt` in my `index.html`. Anyone having idea regarding this please help me out.

Comment: Please show your codes of how you stored the `demo.txt` .

Comment: var pagesDetailFile  = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "demo.txt");  pagesDetailFile.write("hey welcome');

Comment: Add your codes by **editing** your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar technique to read a file:

```
var pagesDetailFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "demo.txt"); 
alert(pagesDetailFile.read()); // Read the file
pagesDetailFile = null; // remember to release the file
```

You should read the documentation carefully for available functions.

Comment: But I need to create function that would read file in index.html. So in short I need a html5 code for reading file from application directory.

Comment: Where do you put the HTML5 code? HTML5 can contain the above JS.

Comment: html5 code is inside Resources/HTML/Site/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the techniques described at https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/platform/latest/#!/guide/Communication_Between_WebViews_and_Titanium to fire an event in the WebView HTML which you'd pick up in Titanium JS, get the file and then use evalJS or fireEvent to send it back to the WebView HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery in order to read data from the simulator and it works for devices too.

```
var filePath = "/Users/anonymous/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FE1CFXXX0AC-D5BD-9615-C58D80B5A9C6/data/Containers/Data/Application/2D25XXXX-4687-B28A-1EA7B7EA3013/Documents/admin/content.txt";
$.ajax({
    url: filePath,
    context: document.body,
    async: false,
    success: function(response){
        Ti.API.info("FILE CONTENT " + response);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert('does not exist');
    }
});
```

filePath is actual path in which we are storing data.